# Creating a TMS from many large TIFF

Tags: software-recommendations, tile-map-service

I have a set of several tiff:s, the largest is 4,7 MB, that I want to create a TMS out of. If I don't want to use Gdal and write commandlines is there a free software option that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to install [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org), add your tiffs as an [Image Mosaic](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/index.html) or as simple [layers](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/geotiff.html) (you don't say if they fit together or not) and then use [GeoWebCache](http://geowebcache.org/docs/1.8.1/index.html) (builtin to GeoServer) to serve up [TMS tiles](http://geowebcache.org/docs/1.8.1/services/tms.html#tms-tile-map-service).

Answer (score 1):

You can upload your Tiffs into http://nextgis.com and get them back as TMS. But each raster will have separate URL. Also stacking on the fly is available (just list all raster styles in TMS url separate by commas).

Details: http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngcom/source/data_upload.html#raster-data

Here is an example of TMS URL: http://bushman.nextgis.com/api/component/render/tile?z=13&x=4784&y=2380&resource=36

[image]

Also you can create webmap like this: http://bushman.nextgis.com/resource/37/display